# How do I replace a string at an undetermined location in a .txt file with a Shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I'm writing a Shell script using Bash to convert a Robot Framework resource file from Windows to Linux. The contents of the Resource file itself are not important, but here is the required "minimal, complete, and verifiable example". `beep` is a typeless empty file used to test a site's ability to upload files.

```
*** Variables ***
${DEFAULT_FILE}     C:\\Users\\user01\\Desktop\\beep
```

There will be an unspecified and ever-changing number of declared variables before and after that variable, so hard-coding the location won't work.

I'd like to change this file, with a Shell script, to the following:

```
*** Variables ***
${DEFAULT_FILE}     //home//user01//Desktop//beep
```

The literals involved are driving me up one wall and down the other, and the errors are similarly driving me nuts. I've tried using `sed`, but the syntax recommendations from Stack Overflow are all over the place.

Here's the most recent version of my code:

```
old="C:\\\\Users\\\\user01\\\\Desktop\\\\beep"
new="//home//user01//Desktop//beep"
sed -i 's|'"${old}"'|'"${new}"'' /home/user01/Desktop/test.txt
```

With my limited Bash experience, I'm sure it's something simple, but for the life of me I can't figure it out. The most recent errors I'm getting follow the pattern `sed: -e expression #1, char [some number here]: unterminated 's' command`. The value of the number changes every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to close pattern `s/foo/bar/` - third `/` is missing.

Please try

```
sed -i 's|'"${old}"'|'"${new}"'|' /home/user01/Desktop/test.txt
```

Now `sed` runs but does not substitute

```
$ old="C:\\\\Users\\\\user01\\\\Desktop\\\\beep"
$ new="//home//user01//Desktop//beep"
$ cat > /tmp/foo
*** Variables ***
${DEFAULT_FILE}     C:\\Users\\user01\\Desktop\\beep
$ sed 's|'"${old}"'|'"${new}"'|' /tmp/foo
*** Variables ***
${DEFAULT_FILE}     C:\\Users\\user01\\Desktop\\beep
```

Need to escape `\` one more time

```
$ old="C:\\\\\\\\Users\\\\\\\\user01\\\\\\\\Desktop\\\\\\\\beep"
$ sed 's|'"${old}"'|'"${new}"'|' /tmp/foo
*** Variables ***
${DEFAULT_FILE}     //home//user01//Desktop//beep
```

---

Ok, what's going on?

Backslash is a special character in `sh`:

```
$ echo \"
"
```

This gives us

```
$ old="C:\\\\Users\\\\user01\\\\Desktop\\\\beep"
$ echo 's|'"${old}"'|'"${new}"'|'
s|C:\\Users\\user01\\Desktop\\beep|//home//user01//Desktop//beep|
```

But backslash also special character in `sed`:

```
$ echo '+' | sed 's/\+/-/'
-
```

So it searches for `C:\Users\user01\Desktop\beep` which is not present in the sample file

Comment: Tried. The console did not return an error, but neither was the file converted. As a side note, the script did appear to run through the file.